# Laravel: Should I stick with camel case names for Eloquent relationship methods?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel encourages us to use snake_case, e.g. first_name, for model attribute names.  In particular, when snake case is used to access an attribute from outside the class, it will automatically look for an accessor named getFirstNameAttribute.

When it comes to model relationships however, it seems more natural to use camel case.  For example, if a stadium has multiple access points, then the `stadium` class might have an `accessPoints()` method.  I can call this method as a property (`$stadium->accessPoints`) to retrieve a list of access points, or I can call it as a method (`$stadium->accessPoints()`) to get an instance of the underlying query builder.

This is different to how I would normally approach naming conventions.  I would normally name attributes using the same case (either snake_case, or camelCase), irrespective of how the attribute is realised.

I am now embarking on a large Laravel project.  Should I stick with the two different syntaxes, or am I likely to regret it down the track?

Comment: Use camelCase for relationship method names and snake_case for attributes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no true convention, like in Assassin's Creed's saying,

> "Nothing is true, everything is permitted"

Laravel follows the PSR-2 coding standard. Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/contributions

Which redirects us to https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md

(from https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md which says: **Code MUST follow all rules outlined in PSR-1.**)

And there it says:

> Whatever naming convention is used SHOULD be applied consistently within a reasonable scope. That scope may be vendor-level, package-level, class-level, or method-level.

And from that declaration, that's related to separation between environment level conventions, such as database design conventions and code conventions. Most database design conventions encourage snake case column names, and most code conventions use camel case method names, class names etc.

And when defining a model, to declare that, that the model property relates with a database column, the coding convention changes from *camelCase* to *snake_case*.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is a convention, so you should use the approach you are more comfortable with.

I personally use snake_case only on column attributes and camelCase on everything else (class names, relationships ecc).

Note that camelCase for class names and methods is basically necessary, because all laravel and external modules classes and methods use camelCase. If you use snake_case, it will be a mess with some methods implemented by you in snake_case and framework methods in camelCase.

For relationships, you will basically only use relationships defined by yourself, so i believe you can really pick the one you prefer.